# batch processing with Google Contacts API - PHP

Tags: php, batch-processing, google-contacts-api

I have been working with the Google Contacts API (v3) and am running into issues with the batch processing. When I make the call (using curl), all I get back is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
    <error/>
</errors>
```

Which is not terribly useful. I have had success with single record processing, but this batch stuff is being a problem. The URL I'm using is:

```
 https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch
```

With the appropriate headers for authentication. My XML input is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
      xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'
      xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
      xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>
<entry gd:etag='"SX09eTVSLit7I2A9XRRaEU4CRwY."'>
    <batch:id>update</batch:id>
    <batch:operation type='update'/>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2008#contact'/>
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/awallace%40ihouseweb.com/base/21df3130886ecccb</id>
    <gContact:externalId label="enduser_acnt"  value="6006838" />
    <gd:name>
        <gd:givenName>Cleopatra</gd:givenName>
        <gd:familyName>Hewlett-Jones</gd:familyName>
    </gd:name>
    <updated>2015-04-15 15:47:08</updated>
    <title type="text">Cleopatra Hewlett-Jones</title>
    <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true">
        <gd:street>12 Override St</gd:street>
        <gd:city>Overridden</gd:city>
        <gd:region>AZ</gd:region>
        <gd:postcode>85253</gd:postcode>
    </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
    <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="cleo123456@nile.com" primary="true" />
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true" >333-444-5555</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false' href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/awallace%40ihouseweb.com/base/7998a9d20900fb66'/>
    <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false' href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/awallace%40ihouseweb.com/base/51ecb7c40e26f4f5'/>
</entry>
</feed>
```

I have validated the XML, as far as I can tell from the documentation it's correct (and worked fine, without the batch wrappers in non-batch mode), and the url is correct. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: How many batch requests are you sending at a time? Only 100 requests are  allowed at a time. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#batch_operations_for_contacts

Comment: I have a limit of 100 set up, but these calls are failing with a batch of 1.